# Is the Firebase Realtime limit on writes per user or per database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase documentation on [Realtime Database limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes) contains this limit for writes:

> **Bytes written**
> **64 MB/minute**
> The total bytes written through simultaneous write operations on the database at any given time.

Is this limitation is for individual user or cumulative users?
if Firebase allow only 64 MB/minute write to cumulative users then it will be not recommended system for large scale applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 64 MB/minute is for all usage against a single database instance.  If you want to scale that, you must create a new database instance and [shard your data across the instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding), giving you more total throughput. From the docs:

> You might want to shard your data across multiple databases if you're using Realtime Database and fit into any of the following scenarios:
>
> - You want to scale beyond the limit of 200,000 simultaneous connections, 1,000 write operations/second, or any of the other limits for a single database instance.

Comment: If I exceed the limit of 1,000 write operations per second for a single database instance in Firebase Realtime Database, will it throw an exception or will the requests be queued?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately so it doesn't get buried in comments.